# Windows 10 - How to make "Save as" window looks always the same?

Tags: windows, windows-10, save-as, dialog

Everytime a new program shows a "Save as dialog window" I've to re-set it to the window's size I like. They always come small, specially the folder tree part. Is there a Register config I could use to set it to always the same size as default? This also applies to Open files dialog, or any other that involves giving a file path to the program.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some limited testing, and this is what I have found.

Windows 10 is pretty good on remembering the Save As dialog size per
application, so one does no longer need the old trick of holding
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while closing the dialog.

Windows 10 will remember your selected columns across applications,
but not the size. For keeping these sizes you need a third party product.

A shareware product that keeps sizes and more is [Direct Folders](http://www.codesector.com/directfolders) ($19.95). However there is a free method.

Using the free macro language [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), one can create a macro that
checks every second for a dialog containing in its title "Save As" or "Open"
and resizes it to a given size.
Here is such a macro ([source](http://drozdman.blogspot.fr/2013/07/autohotkey-scripts-automatically-resize.html)) which you could tailor to your needs :

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, MyTimer, 1000
return
MyTimer:
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
WinMove, Save As,,340,170,800,600
WinMove, Open,,340,170,800,600
return
```

Note that newer Office programs have their own separate methods for
these dialogs.

References :

- [AutoHotkey documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm)
- [AutoHotkey WinMove command](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm)

Comment: Interesting... but how much CPU resources would that instant check consumes?

Comment: Very little - AutoHotkey is very efficient and is the building language for many useful products.

Comment: can I set the size for both the folder tree and the files part?

Comment: I'm sure you can, as one can do almost everything with AHK, but I'm not an advanced enough user.

Comment: I have opened the documentation for WinMove and it doesn't have option for folder three, unfortunately... is there any other command related to window settings?

Comment: The tree is a Windows object, essentially a child window of the parent Explorer window. You need to identify it in order to operate upon it. Explaining how to do that is too heavy for me to do it here. You will need to become an advanced user of AHK.

Comment: Could you just send the code that I should use?

Comment: Sorry, that would take more time than I have available. What you could do as a way to speed-up the writing of such macros, is to use a macro-recorder for AHK that will record the actions you do with the mouse to resize the tree, then modify the macro to make it more general. Try the old `AutoScriptWriter.exe` in the AHK folder, or the newer [Macro Creator](http://www.macrocreator.com/). You will need to learn AHK, no help for it. See for example [this tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).